# Update table column based on comparison of columns from 2 table (SQL)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have the following tables.

Table 1

```
Id | Values | Counts 
1  | rock   |  0
2  | tina   |  0
3  | alex   |  0
```

Table 2

```
Id | Values 
1  | rock
2  | alex
3  | alex
4  | rock
5  | rock
6  | tina
```

As you can see, table 1 contains Values as rock, tina and alex. These column will always have unique values. Counts column should check the count of 'rock' in Table 2 and update it in Counts column. for e.g. rock is shown 3 times in table 2. The counts for rock should be then 3.

Similarly for other values. Can someone pls let me know how can i achieve this using SQL. Here is how the final table should look like.

Table 1

```
Id | Values | Counts 
1  | rock   |  3
2  | tina   |  1
3  | alex   |  2
```

Any help is appreciated. I searched online and couldnot find a possible solution for this scenario.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server ollie..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generally use a `JOIN` between 2 tables to update Table1 with values from Table2 (or further if you are using *bridge* tables).

```
UPDATE t1
SET    t1.dataColumn = t2.dataColumn
FROM   Table1     t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.keyColumn = t2.keyColumn
```

However, when you are using *Aggregate* functions (such as Count, Sum)you must utilize a subquery for the second table and perform the JOIN to that subquery

```
UPDATE t1
SET    t1.Counts = sb.Counts
FROM   Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT    [values], Counts = Count([values])
    FROM      Table2 
    GROUP BY  [values]
    ) AS sb
ON t1.[values] = sb.[values]
```

Running this on your tables gave me this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1

id   values   counts
----  -------  -------
1     rock       3
2     tina       1
3     alex       2
```

One thing concerning your table design; I generally recommend not using reserved/special/key words when naming tables, columns, or other database objects. I also try to avoid using the generic name *id* because it can get confusing when you start linking tables to one another, even idTable1 can make things a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, using a correlated subquery:

```
update t1
set t1.Counts = (
    select count(*) 
    from t2 
    where t2.[Values] = t1.[Values]
    );
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/SBYNB72372

In MySQL, using a correlated subquery:

```
update t1
set t1.Counts = (
    select count(*) 
    from t2 
    where t2.`Values` = t1.`Values`
    );
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DDDC21719

---

Although this sort of thing might be better calculated in a `view` instead of stored in the `t1` table.

In SQL Server:

```
create view dbo.t1_with_counts as 
select t1.Id, t1.[Values], count(t2.[Values]) as Counts
from t1
  left join t2 
    on t1.[Values] = t2.[Values]
group by t1.Id, t1.[Values]
go
select *
from dbo.t1_with_counts;
```

In MySQL:

```
create view t1_with_counts as 
select t1.Id, t1.`Values`, count(t2.`Values`) as Counts
from t1
  left join t2 
    on t1.`Values` = t2.`Values`
group by t1.Id, t1.`Values`;

select *
from t1_with_counts;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would question the wisdom of keeping track of a count in a table like that. That leads to poor relational database structure and management. Instead, I suggest you remove the `count` column from Table 1. Then, whenever you need to see the counts you use a view:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.VALUES, COUNT(t2.ID) AS VALUE_COUNT
FROM TABLE1 t1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.VALUES = t2.VALUES
```

This results in a dynamically updated view of your data instead of a static view that has the potential for going stale without your realizing it.

Comment: It all depends on the situation. In this sample I would agree with you. If this gets called often and there are thousands of rows it could become a performance issue especially if there aren't indexes.